# How can I add or configure an API on API Management service using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I've seen others post this question with PowerShell as the method but we need to run it under Linux and so want the CLI solution.

From looking at the docs, this is not supported with CLI, we even need to use ARM template to create the API Management service but that does not include the APIs that we want to add to the service.

I thought we could use the REST service once the vm was up, but that isn't part of the ARM template either and so you need to go to the portal to turn on the REST (not very scriptable)

So I started looking at the Azure REST APIs, but I'm still at a loss as to how to do this (and if it's even possible)

Can someone give me a working example of adding an OpenAPI to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique to Azure APIM. Azure REST API is always a starting point. You have an option to authenticate interactively via OAuth or to create Service Principal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal?view=azure-cli-latest. After that you're free to use anything that can issue HTTP requests to manage your services.

Comment: I need to be able to fully automate the process. When I visit that page, it talks about using the Portal (which is not my idea of automation), and there is a menu entry for Azure CLI which is great and allows me to create a new service principal account.

However, I still have yet to figure out how to use that to configure the service that is newly created without having to use the portal.

So far, all I see is "go to the portal to create an app service" - can this not be automated?

Comment: This is a one time task to get yourself credentials that you can use from CLI. After that you can automate everything you want.